# Create Pages in Salesforce Using API

Tags: salesforce

I am looking for creating Forms or Pages in Salesforce using  APIs (REST/SOAP). Is it possible to create them dynamically or is it always modelled through VisualForce ?

Any Ideas will be helpful.

Regards,

Srinivas

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to achieve? Is keeping of the Salesforce CSS & functionality on the page important to you?

1. You could create the whole page in javaScript, sending queries to Salesforce (/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js library was available in Salesforce long before REST API became available for external communication).
2. You could create some reusable building blocks in Visualforce (they're called components, basically think about them like a small page+controller... looks similar to portals/portlets etc technique from java world) and dynamically decide if you want to show them or not on your "master" page by setting the "rendered" attribute.
3. You could wait for answer to [Salesforce consuming XML and display data in Visualforce report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106944/salesforce-consuming-xml-and-display-data-in-visualforce-report) about some fancy & dynamic XML processing?
4. You could give up, display a "Web tab" or whatever the name is... Essentially it will load an `<iframe>` in Salesforce, you can point it to whatever other server you have under control and do whatever magic you need querying for data via API.

**Hard to give better answer without more background info.** I'd say that Salesforce already does a lot of dynamic stuff for you (i.e. when you add a field - it asks whether it should be included in page layouts so all views of details & edit screens are aware of new field). Maybe the custom thing for which you need coding solution can actually be achieved without Apex & Visualforce at all?